# Mimicing jquery.mousemove with a drag event on touch screen devices

Tags: jquery

I'm looking to mimic the usage of mousemove on touch screen devices, by dragging a div element.

So far it works great on desktop (you can see it here - http://jsfiddle.net/5DjPw/), but on Mobile using mousemove it simply jumps to where you click the screen, and dragging does nothing.

I've tried using touchmove, which works **slightly** but it isn't a solid movement. I'm having to release and drag, rather than a solid movement.

```
jQuery(".slidswap_moused_over").on('touchmove',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var touch = e.originalEvent.touches[0] || e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0];
      var elm = $(this).offset();
      var x = touch.pageX - elm.left;
      var y = touch.pageY - elm.top;
      jQuery(".slidswap_left_image", this).css({ "width": x });
      jQuery('.slidswap_drag_message', this).css({ "opacity": 0 });
});
```

Any help will be greatfully appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I mimicked this using a combination of [Touch Punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/) and a resizable jQuery call, served on a mobile/tablet only javascript.

The code for the mobile script is here.

```
jQuery(".slidswap_left_image").resizable({
    containment: '.slidswap_image_wrapper',
    handles: "e, w"
});
```

Big thanks to Shane Jones for his help :)